# Quick change directory to a similar directory structure?

Tags: command, cd-command

In the test environment, we have a directory structure for log files that looks like this:

```
/var/Logs/int/app-id/region-code/log/file-name.log
/var/Logs/sat/app-id/region-code/log/file-name.log
/var/Logs/cat/app-id/region-code/log/file-name.log
```

There are many app-ids per environment and several region-codes per app-id (depending on app).

Is there a single command that will allow me to change directory from int to sat, keeping all of the rest of the path the same?  Something like the following:

```
$ pwd
/var/Logs/int/abc/01/log
$ cdswap int sat
$ pwd
/var/Logs/sat/abc/01/log
$ cdswap abc def
$ pwd
/var/Logs/sat/def/01/log
```

It would be a bonus if this also worked:

```
$ cdswap def/01 ghi/02
$ pwd
/var/Logs/sat/ghi/02/log
```

If there is no such command, could I set up an alias that would effectively do the same thing?  How would that look?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `zsh` and `ksh93` both do some stuff like you ask. Emulating it is pretty easily done with `aliases`, functions combined with modifications to the vars `$HOME` and/or `$CDPATH`. Doing `CDPATH=~ HOME=/var/logs` then later `CDPATH=~ cd sat` does what you ask for. Note that setting `CDPATH` ahead of `cd` like that doesn't change its current shell value, so it will still retain the original saved `$HOME` value until you assign it in the current shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In zsh, `cdswap` is… `cd`. When given two arguments, `cd` replaces the first argument by the second argument in the current directory and changes to the resulting directory.

You can emulate this in bash by making `cd` a function.

```
cd () {
  local i=1
  while [[ "${!i}" = -* ]]; do ((++i)); done
  if ((i == $# - 1)); then
    local operands
    operands=("$@")
    operands[$i]=${PWD/${!i}/${!#}}
    if [[ "${operands[$i]}" == "$PWD" ]]; then
      echo >&2 "cd: string not in pwd: ${operands[$i]}"
      return 1
    fi
    set -- "${operands[@]:$(($#-1))}"
  fi
  builtin cd "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `bash` this shell function should do what you want. Remove the `pwd;` if you don't want a visible update of your new directory location.

```
cdswap() { cd "${PWD/$1/$2}"; pwd; }
```

Examples

```
$ cd /usr/local/src
$ pwd
/usr/local/src
$ cdswap src bin
/usr/local/bin
$ pwd
/usr/local/bin
$ cdswap local/bin src
/usr/src
```

Comment: Unless it is your intent that its contents might be interpreted as pattern characters, you need to quote the "$1" param substitution.

Comment: @mikeserv, perhaps it's too late here but I can't see how to quote the `$1` further....?

Comment: `"${PWD/"$1"/$2}"` - also, i don't know whether `bash` handles `&` in the second field or not, but if so you might need to quote `"$2"` - at least i'm pretty sure this is all relevant. Only on my phone now or would have checked already, but definitely pattern chars in `$1` like `"${PWD##*$1}"` can do different stuff than `"${PWD##*"$1"}"`. I assume that `//` thing does the same.

Comment: @mikeserv, thanks. I'll check for implicit pattern matches later tonight if I have time, but I had already ascertained that with `$1="local/bin"` the substitution worked as I would have expected.

Comment: well, yeah, that wouldn't raise any flags for me. For example, if `$1` is `[string]` the `[]` are not interpreted as a POSIX class - just literal characters - and the same is true with `case` patterns but also extends to `|`. It is only `?*` which are problematic.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following:

```
cd $(echo $PWD | sed 's/abc/def/')
```

Make those commands an alias and you're off to the races.

You could also make it a function so you can interchange the files to swap.

```
function cdswap() {
  cd $(echo $PWD | sed 's/$1/$2/')
}
```

Then put that function in your .bash_profile